# Determine: $13^{-1} \pmod {67}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Determine: $13^{-1} \pmod {67}$

I'm not sure how to deal with the negative one here as it inverts the integer? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: They are asking you what number they should multiply $13$ by so that you get $1$ modulo $67$.

Comment: Hint: $31\cdot 13 = 403$.

Comment: @flawr: The hint would be better if you told how you got $31$.

Comment: @Henrik In that case I'd have solved the whole exercise and I'd added it as ans *answer*, not a *hint*.

Answer (score 4):

$67$ is prime, so you know that there exists a number $a$ such that $13\cdot a=1\bmod 67$.

To find it we use the a variant of the division algorithm: $67=5\cdot13+2$, $13=6\cdot2+1$. So working back: $1=13-6\cdot 2=13-6(67-5\cdot13)=31\cdot13-6\cdot67$. Hence we have $31\cdot13=1\bmod 67$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*  to obtain the coefficients $u$ and $v$ of a *Bézout's relation between $13$ and $67$:

[image]

Hence $\;13^{-1}=31$.

Comment: I gather that the $u_i$ are the coefficients of $13$ and that the $v_i$ are the coefficients of $67$ as we solve for $1$ in terms of $13$ and $67$, but that was not clear until I made the calculation \begin{align*} 1 & = 13 - 6 \cdot 2\\ & = 13 - 6(67 - 5 \cdot 13)\\ & = 31 \cdot 13 - 6 \cdot 67\end{align*}

Comment: I felt it a little long to explain the details of the algorithm, I must say. It's not exactly the way you interpret it, because it does not go backwards. Actually, a lemma might be that all successive remainders $r_i$ in the Euclidean algorithm for $a$ and $b$ satisfy a Bézout's relation, and the extended version calculates  their coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to work out many more or less simple examples: search first a multiple of $\;13\;$ as close as possible to a multiple of $\;67\;$ , for example

$$13\cdot5=65=-2\pmod{67}$$

And now work with the much simpler $\;-2\;$ instead. For example, clearly

$$(-2)\cdot34=-68=-1\pmod{67}\implies (-2)(-34)=1\pmod{67}\implies$$

$$(-2)^{-1}=13^{-1}=-34\pmod{67}=33\pmod{67}$$